# Kendo UI Color picker in AngularJS cannot set width

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs, kendo-ui, telerik

Im trying to set width to Kendo Ui color picker using tileSize.width option from documentation:

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/colorpicker#configuration-tileSize.width

By this way:

```
<input style="width: 100%;"  ng-model="warningAttribute.color" kendo-color-picker k-buttons="false" k-tile-size="'{ width: 150 }'" k-preview="false" k-input="false" class="form-control"  placeholder=".col-lg-3">
```

But it is not working for me.

How can I solve it please?

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

If you want square tiles, this works fine:

```
k-tile-size="150"
```